# Pass String from SCALA to Python in Databricks

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have the following question. I want to pass the value of a variable (string) from scala to python in databricks. I know I can transfer dataframe information between the two languages ​​using this command:

```
%scala
scalaDF.registerTempTable("some_table")

%python
spark.table("some_table")
```

But I can't transfer a string this way, any ideas?

Comment: You can't really. Either save it to a new dataframe/rdd or if operating on master node to a file. Yuck.

Answer (score 2):

Create one broadcast variable in scala spark context and get it's value in pyspark context.

Answer (score 2):

You can run a Spark SQL command to save a variable:

```
%scala

spark.sql("set var1 = 'abc'")
```

And in Python you can get it back using

```
%python

spark.sql("select ${var1}").head()[0]
```